# SharePoint 2010 workflow - copy item into Document Sets

Tags: document-set

I am creating a SharePoint Server 2010 workflow in SharePoint Designer 2010.

I want to move document/list item from one document library to another document library under specific **document set**.

Is there any way, that help me to move/copy item into **Document Sets**.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there is no standard SharePoint Designer Action to copy/move a document into a document set. The only similar action is to copy the list item which could copy it from one list to another.

Seems like you will have to create your own [SharePoint Designer Activity](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepointdesigner/archive/2007/03/15/adding-activities-to-spd.aspx) which allows you to move/copy a file to a document set - keep in mind that a document set ultimately is only a folder with metadata so copying to a folder is very similar.